# Illegal instruction in ssl server program

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, openssl

In my ssl program

```
 #define RSA_SERVER_CERT     "server.crt"
 #define RSA_SERVER_KEY      "server.key"
 #define RSA_SERVER_CA_CERT "server_ca.crt"
 #define RSA_SERVER_CA_PATH   "sys$common:[syshlp.examples.ssl]"

 ............

  /* Load the server certificate into the SSL_CTX structure */
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, RSA_SERVER_CERT, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
              exit(1);
   }

   ........
```

This is not working. It gives  **Illegal instruction**

How can I find a solution...

Comment: Which architecture are you compiling for / running this on? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Ubuntu >>gcc -g -I/usr/local/openssl/include -Wall -c -o server.o server.c

Comment: I bet there's a lot of hardware that Ubuntu can run on, so which architecture specifically? x86, x86-64, ARM, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Check the "bitness" of the library you are linking against verses the architecture you target with your gcc. Also make sure openssl was created with no special hardware instruction extensions (for example ARM devices may have neon instruction set extension, x86_64 have AVX, SSE3 and a bunch of others).

Also make sure that you test openssl using the `software` backend.

Comment: Install the development files for openssl and use `gdb` and paste a backtrace when it segfaults.

Comment: gnu debugger - to be honest, if you never heard of that (and given your other comments and questions) I strongly discourage you to write security sensitive applications and expose it on the network beyond playing around.